# Can my Ubuntu laptop be hacked

Tags: hacking

Today I got Ubuntu 21.10 installed on my laptop. By my oversight the technician who installed it has got my username and password and my mobile number. Can he remotely hack my laptop on which Ubuntu is installed? This laptop is not connected to any network except internet.
Thanks,
Amitabh

Comment: Yes, provided that person knows enough, you have enabled remote access and are using a terrible router. Irrespective of this scenario you should change your password.

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Comment: I would also change my username. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 What is the advantage of changing username? I have over 20 years experience in computer security,  and have never encountered  a good reason. Changing one's password to a good, high quality one should suffice.

Comment: If I turn off remote access will that suffice?

Answer (score 2):

In order to 'hack' your system, the "technician" generally needs more than your username/password.

- A stock install of Ubuntu 21.10 does not have any insecure listening services for a hacker to connect to.
- There are also ways to hack your system that don't require your username, nor password, nor physical access to the hardware.

Is your system vulnerable? Sure: ALL systems are vulnerable. Even air-gapped systems have been compromised.

Your goal should be good risk management: Reduce the number of vulnerabilities that you have, and mitigate the damage a compromise might create. There are several easy ways to accomplish both (using Ubuntu is one of them! Regular backups are another.)

Good security is more a set of good habits and a willingness to learn, and less a single magic setting or two.